# google maps API v3 zoomControlOptions LARGE on mobile not displaying the slider

Tags: google-maps, mobile, google-maps-api-3, zooming

I'm setting a map for mobile device and want to utilize the zoom slider.

```
g.map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById("mapcanvas"), 
        {
            disableDoubleClickZoom  : false,
            disableDefaultUI        : true,
            scaleControl            : true,
            panControl              : false,
            navigationControl       : true,
            mapTypeControl          : false,
            zoomControlOptions      : {
                position    : google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM,
                style       : google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
            },
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                mapTypeIds          : [
                                            google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 
                                            google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
                                      ],
                style               : google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
            },
            zoom                    : 16,
            center                  : new google.maps.LatLng('37.8477', '-122.2627'),
            mapTypeId               : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
```

When I look at this on desktop the control is the slider, but on a mobile device, it still displays the small + and - buttons and no slider.

Is this a bug? How can I force the slider for zooming?

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not a bug. The default behaviour for the zoom tool is to display large on large screen devices, and small (just the + -) on smaller screens like phones.

If you would like to always see the larger zoom tool with the slider, you need to set google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE in mapOptions. Ex:

```
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
    }
}
```

Here is my source:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#DefaultUI

Answer (score 0):

You can set the undocumented `controlSize` map option property with an integer value (i.e., 20) for setting the size of the map controls.

Please see the @Dutchmanjonny's post for the latest: [Huge Google Maps Controls (Possible Bug?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51832781/huge-google-maps-controls-possible-bug)