# Huge Google Maps Controls (Possible Bug?)

Tags: css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I first noticed that my Google Maps Controls were **disproportionally large** on my own web app (seen below).

[image]

Initially I thought some of my CSS was playing with Google's CSS on the controls; however, visiting Google's own webpage told me this incident was not isolated to me...

Below is a map on their documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-positioning

[image]

The large controls appear on every page of their documentation for me as well. I tried different machines and different browsers (Chrome and Firefox).

I also tried other sites that used the Google Maps API and saw a similar phenomenon **in some cases**.

[image]

**Is anyone else experiencing the same issues?**

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issues! Hopefully it is just disruptions in the force (s3 or something) and things will be better soon.

Comment: Relieved to hear its not just me haha :) yep - hopefully it gets fixed soon...

Comment: Also seeing this as of ~10 minutes ago or so.

Comment: Looks like the issue isn't a bug - refer to my solution for more details.

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one. I'm also experiencing multiple bugs. White control containers without the actual icons as well as icons completely misaligned inside the container. This update really defaces so many websites.

Comment: They've not only changed CSS sizes, but also changed markup, so what was previously using PNG sprites is now using inline SVGs (as noted in [my duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51865089/5285945)) so this change might have other unintended styling consequences as it did for me.

Comment: I'm seeing the button images themselves being stacked vertically instead of on top of each other, making everything have 3 buttons.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Turns out this isn't a bug. [See more here:](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112520084)

> Aug 13, 2018 03:56PM  Reported Issue Google Maps JavaScript API weekly
>   channel (3.34) will be using the larger control UI.
>
> As we are seeing increases of touch operations on various devices, we
>   adjusted the control UI to fit for both finger touches and mouse
>   clicks.
>
> It's possible to opt out of this by loading the API with v=quarterly,
>   v=3, v=3.33 or v=3.32. Note: requests to retired version will receive
>   the default channel, see [1](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112520084).
>
> If you have any requests or other issues concerning the new control UI
>   please let us know.
>
> [1](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112520084) https://issuetracker.google.com/112519576

Use **v=quarterly, v=3, v=3.33 or v=3.32** when loading the API to use smaller controls.

**EDIT:**

Refer to answer from @Jonny van Beek on how to scale Google map's controls to the size of your choosing.

Refer to answers from @garethdn and @Peter (below) to find out how to replace Google's large controls with your own custom controls.

**Refer to @Dutchmanjonny's post (below) for latest and correct solution to this problem.**

Comment: That's a **temporary solution** as the versions will be updated and become unavailable. That said, Google might provide some customization setting in a later version. If you need full control over these buttons, you better go with @garethdn answer and create your own custom controls.

Comment: I'd say creating your own controls isn't exactly the best answer, at least if you are just wanting the existing controls but at smaller size. I say this because Google Maps already does localization for languages around the world. If you replace the control, you will need to do all this localization yourself. That's any button text as well as the flyover hints.

Comment: Custom controls also don't account for all controls, notably the pegman, rotate/tilt, and terrain/labels options are missing from their examples and undocumented.

Answer (score 50):

Looks like google have now acknowledged this and have provided a (currently un-documented) feature to change the UI scaling by passing in a "controlSize" when creating the map.

See comment from Google [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112520084#comment30).

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4hjar1v5/) (from comment above).

Sample code:

```
var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8,
    controlSize: 32,
  });
}
```

Note: 40 is the default currently (and corresponds to the large controls that this question is about). I've found 25 to be about the same as the previous controls.

**Update:**

As of v3.36 this is a documented feature, see [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions.controlSize)

Comment: With the impeding loss of api version 3.33 we're now forced to 3.34+. So v3.35 supports controlSize well. I found that controlSize: 26 looks closest to the 3.33 look. JSFiddle with forced 3.35 and controlSize: 26 here: https://jsfiddle.net/blalond/8q6fjthg/

Answer (score 5):

For those that are reluctant to opt out by specifying older versions of the API, creating custom controls is relatively straight forward. The following will create two `button` elements to zoom in and out.

```
defaultMapOptions: google.maps.MapOptions = {
    // Hide Google's default zoom controls
    zoomControl: false
};

initializeMap(el: HTMLElement, options?: google.maps.MapOptions): google.maps.Map {
    let opts = Object.assign({}, this.defaultMapOptions, options);
    let map = new google.maps.Map(el, opts);
    let zoomControlsDiv = document.createElement('div');
    // Add a class to the container to allow you to refine the position of the zoom controls
    zoomControlsDiv.classList.add('google-map-custom-zoom-controls');

    this.createCustomZoomControls(zoomControlsDiv, map);

    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(zoomControlsDiv);

    return map;
}

createCustomZoomControls(controlDiv: HTMLDivElement, map: google.maps.Map) {
    let zoomInControlUI: HTMLButtonElement = document.createElement('button');
    let zoomOutControlUI: HTMLButtonElement = document.createElement('button');
    let zoomControls: HTMLButtonElement[] = [zoomInControlUI, zoomOutControlUI];
    // List of classes to be applied to each zoom control
    let buttonClasses: string[] = ['btn', 'btn-primary', 'btn-sm'];

    zoomInControlUI.innerHTML = `&plus;`;
    zoomOutControlUI.innerHTML = `&minus;`;

    zoomControls.forEach(zc => {
        zc.classList.add(...buttonClasses);
        controlDiv.appendChild(zc);
    });

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(zoomInControlUI, 'click', () => map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1));
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(zoomOutControlUI, 'click', () => map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1));
}

let map = this.initializeMap(myGoogleMapContainerElement);
```

Answer (score 5):

After the backlash, Google has now published an example for how to replace the default (big) controls: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-replacement

Here is the code as published by Google:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Replacing Default Controls</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      .gm-style .controls {
        font-size: 28px;  /* this adjusts the size of all the controls */

        background-color: white;
        box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 4px -1px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border-radius: 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-weight: 300;
        height: 1em;
        margin: 6px;
        text-align: center;
        user-select: none;
        padding: 2px;
        width: 1em;
      }
      .gm-style .controls button {
        border: 0;
        background-color: white;
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
      }
      .gm-style .controls button:hover {
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
      }

      .gm-style .controls.zoom-control {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: auto;
      }
      .gm-style .controls.zoom-control button {
        font: 0.85em Arial;
        margin: 1px;
        padding: 0;
      }

      .gm-style .controls.maptype-control {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        width: auto;
      }
      .gm-style .controls.maptype-control button {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 0.5em;
        margin: 0 1px;
        padding: 0 6px;
      }
      .gm-style .controls.maptype-control.maptype-control-is-map .maptype-control-map     {
        font-weight: 700;
      }
      .gm-style .controls.maptype-control.maptype-control-is-satellite .maptype-control-satellite {
        font-weight: 700;
      }

      .gm-style .controls.fullscreen-control button {
        display: block;
        font-size: 1em;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%
      }
      .gm-style .controls.fullscreen-control .fullscreen-control-icon {
        border-style: solid;
        height: 0.25em;
        position:absolute;
        width: 0.25em;
      }
      .gm-style .controls.fullscreen-control .fullscreen-control-icon.fullscreen-    control-top-left {
        border-width: 2px 0 0 2px;
        left: 0.1em;
        top: 0.1em;
      }
      .gm-style .controls.fullscreen-control.is-fullscreen .fullscreen-control-icon.fullscreen-control-top-left {
        border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
      }
      .gm-style .controls.fullscreen-control .fullscreen-control-icon.fullscreen-control-top-right {
        border-width: 2px 2px 0 0;
        right: 0.1em;
        top: 0.1em;
      }
      .gm-style .controls.fullscreen-control.is-fullscreen .fullscreen-control-icon.fullscreen-control-top-right {
        border-width: 0 0 2px 2px;
      }
      .gm-style .controls.fullscreen-control .fullscreen-control-icon.fullscreen-control-bottom-left {
        border-width: 0 0 2px 2px;
        left: 0.1em;
        bottom: 0.1em;
      }
      .gm-style .controls.fullscreen-control.is-fullscreen .fullscreen-control-icon.fullscreen-control-bottom-left {
        border-width: 2px 2px 0 0;
      }
      .gm-style .controls.fullscreen-control .fullscreen-control-icon.fullscreen-control-bottom-right {
        border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
        right: 0.1em;
        bottom: 0.1em;
      }
      .gm-style .controls.fullscreen-control.is-fullscreen .fullscreen-control-icon.fullscreen-control-bottom-right {
        border-width: 2px 0 0 2px;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <!-- Hide controls until they are moved into the map. -->
    <div style="display:none">
      <div class="controls zoom-control">
        <button class="zoom-control-in" title="Zoom In">+</button>
        <button class="zoom-control-out" title="Zoom Out">−</button>
      </div>
      <div class="controls maptype-control maptype-control-is-map">
        <button class="maptype-control-map"
                title="Show road map">Map</button>
        <button class="maptype-control-satellite"
                title="Show satellite imagery">Satellite</button>
      </div>
      <div class="controls fullscreen-control">
        <button title="Toggle Fullscreen">
          <div class="fullscreen-control-icon fullscreen-control-top-left"></div>
          <div class="fullscreen-control-icon fullscreen-control-top-right"></div>
          <div class="fullscreen-control-icon fullscreen-control-bottom-left"></div>
          <div class="fullscreen-control-icon fullscreen-control-bottom-right"></div>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector('#map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8,
          disableDefaultUI: true,
        });

        initZoomControl(map);
        initMapTypeControl(map);
        initFullscreenControl(map);
      }

      function initZoomControl(map) {
        document.querySelector('.zoom-control-in').onclick = function() {
          map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
        };
        document.querySelector('.zoom-control-out').onclick = function() {
          map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1);
        };
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(
            document.querySelector('.zoom-control'));
      }

      function initMapTypeControl(map) {
        var mapTypeControlDiv = document.querySelector('.maptype-control');
        document.querySelector('.maptype-control-map').onclick = function() {
          mapTypeControlDiv.classList.add('maptype-control-is-map');
          mapTypeControlDiv.classList.remove('maptype-control-is-satellite');
          map.setMapTypeId('roadmap');
        };
        document.querySelector('.maptype-control-satellite').onclick =
            function() {
          mapTypeControlDiv.classList.remove('maptype-control-is-map');
          mapTypeControlDiv.classList.add('maptype-control-is-satellite');
          map.setMapTypeId('hybrid');
        };

        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP].push(
            mapTypeControlDiv);
      }

      function initFullscreenControl(map) {
        var elementToSendFullscreen = map.getDiv().firstChild;
        var fullscreenControl = document.querySelector('.fullscreen-control');
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP].push(
            fullscreenControl);


        fullscreenControl.onclick = function() {
          if (isFullscreen(elementToSendFullscreen)) {
            exitFullscreen();
          } else {
            requestFullscreen(elementToSendFullscreen);
          }
        };

        document.onwebkitfullscreenchange =
        document.onmsfullscreenchange =
        document.onmozfullscreenchange =
        document.onfullscreenchange = function() {
          if (isFullscreen(elementToSendFullscreen)) {
            fullscreenControl.classList.add('is-fullscreen');
          } else {
            fullscreenControl.classList.remove('is-fullscreen');
          }
        };
      }

      function isFullscreen(element) {
        return (document.fullscreenElement ||
                document.webkitFullscreenElement ||
                document.mozFullScreenElement ||
                document.msFullscreenElement) == element;
      }
      function requestFullscreen(element) {
        if (element.requestFullscreen) {
          element.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
          element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
          element.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (element.msRequestFullScreen) {
          element.msRequestFullScreen();
        }
      }
      function exitFullscreen() {
        if (document.exitFullscreen) {
          document.exitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
          document.webkitExitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
          document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.msCancelFullScreen) {
          document.msCancelFullScreen();
        }
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?    key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I mentioned this on the chosen answer, but a notable problem with this is that custom controls don't account for all controls, notably the pegman, rotate/tilt, and terrain/labels options are missing from their examples and undocumented.

Comment: **Never** use undocumented properties / classnames. This is not the way to go.

Comment: @MrUpsidown, maybe you didn't read my comment? "Google has now published an example". That's documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what did it for me:

```
 .gm-bundled-control
,.gm-style-mtc
,.gm-fullscreen-control{
    transform: scale(.7);
}
```

Makes the controls 30% smaller.

Answer (score -1):

I added some css and that's it.

```css
/* Fix +/- zoom buttons design */
#map .gm-bundled-control-on-bottom {
  right: 30px !important;
  bottom: 116px !important;
}
#map .gm-bundled-control-on-bottom > div:first-child {
   top: 44px !important;
}
#map .gmnoprint > .gmnoprint > div {
  height: 60px !important;
  width: 30px !important;
}
#map .gmnoprint > .gmnoprint > div > div { /* seperator */
  width: 22.5px !important;
  margin: 0px 3.75px !important;
}
#map .gmnoprint > .gmnoprint button {
  width: 30px !important;
  height: 30px !important;
}
#map .gmnoprint > .gmnoprint button img {
  height: 13.5px !important;
  width: 13.5px !important;
  margin: 6.75px 8.25px 9.75px !important;
}
```

and this is for the yellow man button:

```css
/* yellow person button design*/
#map .gm-svpc {
 width: 30px !important;
 height: 30px !important;
}
#map .gm-svpc img:nth-child(1), #map .gm-svpc img:nth-child(2){
 width: 13.5px !important;
 height: 22.5px !important;
 left: -7px !important;
 top: -12px !important;
}
#map .gm-svpc img:nth-child(3) {
 width: 24px !important;
 height: 30px !important;
}
```

and for last the MAP|Satellite buttons design

```css
/* MAP|Satellite buttons design*/
#map .gm-style-mtc > div:nth-child(1) {
  padding: 0px 9px !important;
  height: 30px !important;  
  font-size: 15px !important;
}
#map .gm-style-mtc > div:nth-child(2) {
  top: 30px !important;
}
#map .gm-style-mtc > div:nth-child(2) > div {
  padding: 2px 4px 2px 2px !important;
  font-size: 14px !important;
}
```

Comment: While this probably does work atm - I think people’s biggest concern with this approach is that these class names are not well documented and also subject to change if Google decides they want to use different class names

Comment: Do you have styles for the full screen button as well?