# Google Maps control buttons are too big after version update to 3.34

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google updated [Google Maps JavaScript API V3 Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/) on August 13, 2018 to v3.34. Currently there are no release notes. I have noticed that our website zoom and map type select buttons are significantly bigger than before. Also it seems that this change affects many other websites. Controls are default which are taken from Google API. When I change version to `v=3.33` they become right size as before. However, `v=3.33` will be deprecated in few months.  Should I wait for Google fix? Or use `v3.34` and make custom controls?

[image]

Comment: What is the right size? You are using a Google product. Google can change its aspects whenever they want. I see 4 solutions: 1) Ask Google to provide more flexibility 2) Create your own controls 3) Live with it 4) Use another product.

Comment: It's like changing API - of course company can change it but affects lots of users. They could left buttons the same size as before but add functionality to change size. HTML structure was also changed so who replaces CSS style needs to modify their code.

Comment: I would strongly advise you to **never** change the aspect of their product via undocumented JS/CSS exactly for that reason. When they change the HTML markup, CSS class names, etc. then your code stops working and needs adjustments. Sure they could have provided more flexibility but they didn't. You can create a feature request though (or subscribe to an existing one) in the hope that they will do something.

Comment: I agree that changing CSS is not a good way, it's a hack. If you would check duplicate thread, it's already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51832781/huge-google-maps-controls-possible-bug

Comment: I've seen that post. But that's a short term solution. Older API versions are deprecated after some time. Better to subscribe to the feature request IMO.