# Google Maps API - Customising the Appearance of certain controls

Tags: google-maps-api-3

We're using the Google Maps API and have noticed that the appearance of some of the controls have changed recently. For example the size of the zoom controls:

[image]

and the map type:

[image]

appear to have increased in font size. We've also noticed this icon in the bottom right corner above the zoom controls:

[image]

and not sure what this is and would like to hide this if possible. Is it possible to reduce the size of the zoom controls and the Map Type text, as well as remove this person icon?

Comment: All controls can be individually disabled (MapOptions interface). You can also create your own custom controls with your own styling if needed. All that is explained, in details, in the documentation.

Comment: related question: [Huge Google Maps Controls (Possible Bug?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51832781/huge-google-maps-controls-possible-bug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns it was an issue with the latest 3.34 release of the Google Maps JavaScript API. I've managed to revert to the previous version for now, e.g. http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.33&key=xxxxxxx

Comment: This was the solution for me. Considering that Google is banging on about "mobile first", it's strange that they should introduce this change that makes the controls look so big and clunky on mobile devices. (I hadn't notices the change on my desktop.)