# Sudden increase in size of Google Maps controls?

Tags: google-maps

After leaving work yesterday and coming back today, the Controls on our Google Maps (things like the "Maps | Satellite" switcher, "Full Screen" icon, zoom buttons, Street View man) are suddenly displaying larger than they were before, on all my browsers.  I have a few tabs still open from yesterday where you can see the difference in these screenshots.

Yesterday:

[image]

Today:

[image]

From inspecting the DOM, I see differences in the CSS and markup.  For example, the `font-size` set directly on the div containing the "Map" and "Satellite" text is now `18px` instead of `11px`.  And the markup for the "Full Screen" icon as grabbed from an old tab:

```
<button style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; margin: 10px 14px; padding: 0px; position: absolute; cursor: pointer; -moz-user-select: none; width: 25px; height: 25px; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; right: 0px;" draggable="false" title="Toggle fullscreen view" aria-label="Toggle fullscreen view" type="button">
  <img style="position: absolute; left: -52px; top: -86px; width: 164px; height: 175px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" alt="" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/sv9.png" draggable="false" class="gm-fullscreen-control">
</button>
```

versus a page in a tab loaded today:

```
<button style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; margin: 10px; padding: 0px; position: absolute; cursor: pointer; -moz-user-select: none; border-radius: 2px; height: 40px; width: 40px; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 4px -1px; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; right: 0px;" draggable="false" title="Toggle fullscreen view" aria-label="Toggle fullscreen view" type="button" class="gm-control-active gm-fullscreen-control">
  <img style="height: 18px; width: 18px; padding: 8px 3px 10px; margin-top: 3px;" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%2218%22%20height%3D%2218%22%20viewBox%3D%220%20018%2018%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23666%22%20d%3D%22M0%2C0v2v4h2V2h4V0H2H0z%20M16%2C0h-4v2h4v4h2V2V0H16z%20M16%2C16h-4v2h4h2v-2v-4h-2V16z%20M2%2C12H0v4v2h2h4v-2H2V12z%22%2F%3E%0A%3C%2Fsvg%3E%0A">
  <img style="height: 18px; width: 18px; padding: 8px 3px 10px; margin-top: 3px;" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%2218%22%20height%3D%2218%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2018%2018%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23333%22%20d%3D%22M0%2C0v2v4h2V2h4V0H2H0z%20M16%2C0h-4v2h4v4h2V2V0H16z%20M16%2C16h-4v2h4h2v-2v-4h-2V16z%20M2%2C12H0v4v2h2h4v-2H2V12z%22%2F%3E%0A%3C%2Fsvg%3E%0A">
  <img style="height: 18px; width: 18px; padding: 8px 3px 10px; margin-top: 3px;" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%2218%22%20height%3D%2218%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2018%2018%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23111%22%20d%3D%22M0%2C0v2v4h2V2h4V0H2H0z%20M16%2C0h-4v2h4v4h2V2V0H16z%20M16%2C16h-4v2h4h2v-2v-4h-2V16z%20M2%2C12H0v4v2h2h4v-2H2V12z%22%2F%3E%0A%3C%2Fsvg%3E%0A">
</button>
```

The change from the .png (where there was a white background over that part of the sprite) to the SVGs seems to also explain the change in the background color of the icon on my site (see above screenshots), which are getting affected today by some `!important` declarations set elsewhere (I know, I know, bad, bad, but long story).

I could imagine the bump up to 18px might be an accessibility-related thing, but I guess my questions are:

1. Am I the only seeing this change on their sites or am I going crazy? (I'm also seeing the new/big controls in the examples in the API docs today.)
2. Is there a way to be notified of such changes before they're released? For example, I'm not seeing mentions at the [Google Maps blog](https://www.blog.google/products/maps/), the [Google Maps Platform Important Updates page](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/important-updates), the [New Renderer page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/new-renderer), the [New Base Map page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basemap) (which has screenshots w/ the old sizes), or the [Controls page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls).

Comment: Where is the link then?

Comment: @guruguldmand the link to ... the duplicate? It's at https://stackoverflow.com/q/51832781/5285945 (linked from the top ... I don't know why SO separates the "already an answer" stuff at top from the "marked as duplicate" stuff at bottom). Or are you asking about some other link?