# How to change the size of Google Maps API controls?

Tags: google-maps

Google Maps API just dramatically increased the size of the default map controls (map type, zoom, full screen, etc).  How can I change their size?

Comment: How is this too broad?

Comment: How is this not too broad, a duplicate and a very low quality question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Huge Google Maps Controls (Possible Bug?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51832781/huge-google-maps-controls-possible-bug)

Comment: The duplicated question reads actually "Possible Bug?" and "Is anyone else experiencing the same issues?" and not "How to change the size?". Although it produced a relevant answer to the second inherent question as well. I am not interested in knowing if it is a bug (it is not) but I'm looking for solutions how I can change the size. So this is a relevant question for me!

Comment: @ToniTornado maybe the question was asked in a different way but the answer is still perfectly valid.

Answer (score 9):

You can set the size of the controls by setting `controlSize` in options when creating the map.

```js
let map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 8,
    controlSize: 20,
  });
}
```

```css
#map {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change size of maps controls but you can create custom controls/views and handle their clicks to perform required task. E.g. Create zoom in/out controls and then set their click listeners,

```
    fabZoomIn.setOnClickListener(this);
    fabZoomOut.setOnClickListener(this);
```

so when user clicks on these control you get callback and you can call appropriate function.
This is how I do it in my app:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.fabZoomInDashboard:
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
            break;
        case R.id.fabZoomOutDashboard:
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomOut());
            break;
    }
}
```

fabZoomIn and fabZoomOut are custom controls added in layout for zoom. You can do same for other controls.